# Getting list of 1st elements from a list?

Tags: list, kotlin, dictionary, flatmap

I have the following data class

```
data class AdDetails(val adMedia: List<AdMedia>)

data class AdMedia(val adMetaInfo: AdMetaInfo, val adUri:List<AdUri>)
data class AdUri(val width:Int,val height:Int,val uri:String)
data class AdMetaInfo(var adTitle: String, var adId: String)
```

This is the smaple data

```
AdDetails(adMedia=[AdMedia(adMetaInfo=AdMetaInfo(adTitle=1, adId=1), 
adUri=[AdUri(width=640, height=360, uri=adUrl1), 
AdUri(width=426, height=240, uri=url3)])])

AdDetails(adMedia=[AdMedia(adMetaInfo=AdMetaInfo(adTitle=2, adId=2), 
adUri=[AdUri(width=640, height=360, uri=adUrl2), 
AdUri(width=426, height=240, uri=url3)])])
```

From this I want list of only 1st ad URI - adUrl1 , adUrl2

I am using map / flatmap for this but not getting desired output

```
 val preRollUri=preRollAdDetails.adMedia.flatMap { it.adUri.map { it.uri } }
```

Comment: What if there are multiple `AdMedia` in the `AdDetails`? Can you show an example of your expected output when there are multiple `AddMedia`?

Comment: Also, is the sample data supposed to be a `List<AdDetails>`? But `preRollAdDetails` seems to just be a single `AdDetails`.

Comment: @WISHY Please update your sample data to reflect the data classes, or the data classes to reflect the sample date (for example: _width=426_ (an Integer) does not match with: _val width: String_, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data class AdDetails(val adMedia: List<AdMedia>)
data class AdMedia(val adMetaInfo: AdMetaInfo, val adUri: List<AdUri>)
data class AdMetaInfo(var adTitle: String, var adId: String)
data class AdUri(val width: String, val height: String, val uri: String)

val details = AdDetails(
  listOf(
    AdMedia(
      AdMetaInfo("1", "1"),
      listOf(
        AdUri("640", "360", "adUrl1"),
        AdUri("426", "240", "url3")
      )
    ),
    AdMedia(
      AdMetaInfo("2", "2"),
      listOf(
        AdUri("640", "360", "adUrl2"),
        AdUri("426", "240", "url3")
      )
    ),
    AdMedia(
      AdMetaInfo("3", "3"),
      emptyList()
    )
  )
)

val result = details.adMedia.map { it.adUri.firstOrNull()?.uri }

println(result)   // Output: [adUrl1, adUrl2, null]
```

To filter out null values:

```
val result = details.adMedia.map { it.adUri.firstOrNull()?.uri }.filterNotNull()

println(result)   // Output: [adUrl1, adUrl2]
```

If it is guaranteed that there won't be any empty list in any of the AdUris in any of the AdMedias, the following will do (but would crash if there is an empty list):

```
val result = details.adMedia.map { it.adUri.first().uri }
```